# how to fix csp bug with pug, sass, gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, pug

This is my project structure: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiUWL.png)

My gulpfile.js :

```js
const gulp = require("gulp");
const pug = require("gulp-pug");
const sass = require('gulp-sass')(require('sass'));
const browserSync = require("browser-sync").create();
const htmlPrettify = require('gulp-html-prettify');

//  Pug -> HTML
gulp.task("pug", () => {
    return gulp
        .src("src/pug/pages/*.pug")
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(htmlPrettify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/html"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

//  SCSS -> CSS
gulp.task("sass", () => {
    return gulp
        .src("src/assets/sass/main.scss")
        .pipe(sass().on("error", sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest("dist/css"))
        .pipe(browserSync.stream());
});

// BrowserSync
gulp.task("serve", () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: "./dist",
    });

    gulp.watch("src/pug/**/*.pug", gulp.series("pug"));
    gulp.watch("src/assets/sass/**/*.scss", gulp.series("sass"));
});

// task
gulp.task("default", gulp.parallel("pug", "sass", "serve"));
```

When i run gulp the browser goes to localhost:3000 but it crashes. I looked at the console and got an error: Content-Security-Policy: The page's settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“default-src”).

i thought it was due to BrowserSync in gulp because when i run gulp i see inline script I tried to change but it didnt work

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, i wrote wrong path in gulp and when running it read the index file leading to this error. Here is the code of gulp I edited:

```
gulp.task("serve", () => {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: "./dist/html",
            index: "home.html",
        },
    });
    gulp.watch("src/pug/**/*.pug", gulp.series("pug"));
    gulp.watch("src/assets/sass/**/*.scss", gulp.series("sass"));
});
```